# How to detect number in certain range

Tags: discord.py

Trying to get bot to send a message when the person sends a message in range

```py
async def on_message(message):
  if 0 < Message < 100 in message.content:
   await bot.message.send(message.channel, "you are in Bronze 1")
```

Comment: Where does the `Message` come from?

Comment: Really clueless so it’s meant to be if the number in the message is between 0 and 100

Comment: Should the number be apart of the message? or the message itself?

Comment: Just the message itself

Comment: Apart is also fine though

Comment: Also, please fix your formatting with three backticks. (```) in front of the entire code and on the end. (As well as fixing your indentation).

Comment: Sry I’m on mobile it didn’t let me do back ticks same with the format sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first of all. Please don't code on mobile. Especially not python. That will mess things up way too much.

Second, please define your variables properly. `Message` is not a defined variable. It will return an error.

So, as you said, you wanted two ways to do this. The number should be the message itself, or within the message.

For the first example, all you have to do is cast the `message.content` to int. Then you can check if it's in the range.

```py
if 0 < int(message.content) < 100:
    ...
```

For the second example, you will have to do something similar, however, you should split the entire `message.content` string and convert the number ones into integers. I'm assuming that the number will not be within a word and it will be by itself.

```py
for word in message.content.split():
    if word.isnumeric():
        num = int(word)
        if 0 < num < 100:
            ... # return and send message to avoid spamming
```